# Run a VBScript in HTML - invoke function by clicking a button doesn't work

Tags: html, vbscript

I wrote a VBscript to control a excel workbook, i don't have any problem with calling it from command line. 
The problem occurs when i am trying to invoke it from html: I keep getting error saying my "RunBatch is undefined " ? ( Right now i am testing on my local and using IE 11. ) 
At the first place, i tried to add the url of my vbscript to (i.e as external file), since it doesn't work i add my code to "`<script>`" 
i think the problem is on :

```html
<input type="button" onclick=" RunBatch(fnam)" value="Click To Test" />
```

But I failed to fix it, searched a lot online, still get the same error

Here is my script:

```html
 <html>
    <head>
                <h1>
                <title>Testing Interface</title>
                </h1>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
</head>
<script type="text/vbscript" language="VBScript">
optioin explicit
sub RunBatch(fname)
                Dim oWorkBook
                Dim xlObj
                Dim oShell
                Dim oFS
                Dim wsBatch
                Dim wsBatchMap
                Dim filePath
                Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
                Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                Set oFS = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set filePath = oFS.GetFolder("F:\User Files\....\Testing")
                fname = filePath.Path&"\"&fname
                xlObj.DisplayAlerts = False
                xlObj.AskToUpdateLinks = False
                xlObj.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
                xlObj.Visible = False
 
                Set oWorkBook = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(fname,0)
                Set wsBatch = xlObj.Worksheets("xx")
                Set wsBatchMap = xlObj.Worksheets("xxxxx")
                     xlObj.Workbooks.Open(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")&"\xx.xlam")
              'config ur range
               wsBatchMap.Range("J6") = 1
               wsBatchMap.Range("K6") = 10                
               xlObj.Run "XXX.xlam!xxfunction",   xlObj.Workbooks(oWorkBook.Name), _
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 xlObj.Workbooks(oWorkBook.Name).Worksheets("xx"), _
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 xlObj.Workbooks(oWorkBook.Name).Worksheets("xxxx"), _
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 False                     on error resume next
                if err.number <> 0 Then
                on error goto 0
                oShell.Echo "Runtime Error "&err.number&"workbook will be closed"
                err.clear
                oWorkBook.Save
                oWorkBook.Close                        
                Set oWorkBook = Nothing
                if xlObj.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
                   xlObj.Quit
                End If
                Set oWorkBook = Nothing
                Set args = Nothing
                Set xlObj = Nothing
                Set oShell = Nothing
                Set oFS  = Nothing          
                document.write ".Done"
End sub
</script>
<body BGCOLOR="white">
                <h1>Testing Interface</h1>
                input Testing File Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="fname">
                <br />
                <input type="button" onclick=" RunBatch(fnam)" value="Click To Test" />
</body>
</html>
 `
```

Comment: How about simplifying this?  Try `Sub RunBatch()`, `End Sub` and see if you get the same error. I'm not sure that IE still supports VBScript.

Comment: Good call, i just find out IE 11 doesnt support vbscript :(  ... So I change it to : <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"> use IE 10 .... still doesn't work. any thought ?

Comment: Yeah - don't use VBScript. Also, I really doubt your script would ever have worked. You just can't _do_ most things from a browser. In general, a browser can't access client resources, like the file system and programs installed on the client (like Excel).

Comment: Thank you John, the vbscript works well without html. I just tried a simple "hello world" one...  still doesn't work :( I guess it has something to do with the security setting / Compatibility setting .

Comment: I mean you can't do these sorts of things from a web browser. They are considered serious security problems. What if a script like yours was loaded from a web site?

Comment: yes, I agree, I do face security problems .... may be I should try HTA I think. I am not a scripting guy, but I want to figure out something

Comment: Why fight a browser if you need to do desktop things?

Comment: well.... senior (old) ppl in my company know nothing about script or command line( they have different background)... so need a interface so that they can put values. otherwise there is no way for them to run a job..... the interface will be on their local and it will be easier for them to do things with their local file

Comment: So write a desktop (Winforms) application they can configure and use. Thus says a senior (old) person. :-)

Comment: Sounds good ! ( in fact I never heard it ) I will try it thank you John :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fix the typo "optioin explicit"
2. Fix the invalid HTML (at least: nothing is allowed between `</head><body>`; move the script into the head)
3. See that fnam has a value, when the button is pressed (maybe: `onclick="RunBatch fname.value"`)
4. `on error goto 0` clears the Err object; the info is lost.

Comment: Em..... thanks! I fixed the html error, removed ".value" after RunBatch, removed the space, typo, cleaned the "on error goto 0 " ....etc. it still saying "RunBatch" undefined ........ ?  could it be the IE security setting or ?